# I have a problem writing a custom distribution

Tags: functions, distributions

I wrote the [Frechet Distribution](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/334884635_On_a_Bivariate_Frechet_Distribution) as follows:

```
dist1 = ProbabilityDistribution[{"PDF", \[Lambda]1/\[Alpha]1 (x/\[Alpha]1)^(-\[Lambda]1 - 1)E^-((x/\[Alpha]1)^-\[Lambda]1)}, {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, Assumptions -> {\[Lambda]1 > 0, \[Alpha]1 > 0}]
dist2 = ProbabilityDistribution[{"PDF", \[Lambda]2/\[Alpha]2 (x/\[Alpha]2)^(-\[Lambda]2 - 1)E^-((x/\[Alpha]2)^-\[Lambda]2)}, {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, Assumptions -> {\[Lambda]2 > 0, \[Alpha]2 > 0}]

bidist = CopulaDistribution[{"FGM", \[Gamma]}, {dist1, dist2}]
```

when i write  cdf of coupla dist1,dist2 as follows

```
CDF[bidist, {x, y}]
```

The output is as follows:

[image: 11]

That is not the output from the linked publication.

[image: d3]

I want to find maximum likelihood
of FGM copula, if it is possible.

Comment: If you want the result in a particular form, explicitly include that form in your question rather than providing a link to some article that has the form somewhere in the article. If a built-in distribution exists, use it rather than `ProbabilityDistribution`: `bidist = CopulaDistribution[{"FGM", \[Gamma]}, {FrechetDistribution[\[Lambda][1], \[Alpha][1]], FrechetDistribution[\[Lambda][2], \[Alpha][2]]}];`

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

(Format[#[n_]] := Subscript[#, n]) & /@ {α, λ, x, y};

bidist = CopulaDistribution[{"FGM", θ},
   {FrechetDistribution[λ[1], α[1]], 
    FrechetDistribution[λ[2], α[2]]}];

$Assumptions = DistributionParameterAssumptions[bidist]
```

[image]

```
Assuming[x > 0 && y > 0, CDF[bidist, {x, y}] // Simplify]
```

[image]

```
data = Transpose[Array[#, 5] & /@ {x, y}]
```

[image]

```
Assuming[x[_] > 0 && y[_] > 0, Likelihood[bidist, data]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I wonder if the problem is a bug in `ProbabilityDistribution`.

Using *Mathematica* 13.1 (Windows 10):

```
dist = ProbabilityDistribution[{"PDF", (λ/α) (x/α)^(-λ - 1) Exp[-((x/α)^(-λ))]}, 
  {x, 0, ∞}, Assumptions -> {λ > 0, α > 0}];
```

The (symbolic) pdf is correct:

```
PDF[dist, z]
```

[image: Symbolic pdf]

But the symbolic cdf is not correct:

```
CDF[dist, z]
```

[image: Symbolic cdf]

which is essentially

```
-1 + E^-(z/α)^-λ
```

The correct cdf is $e^{-\left(\frac{\alpha }{z}\right)^{\lambda }}$.

Comment: Yes, I mean this is problem in writing

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: The cdf is not correct when I write. CDF[dist,x]

Comment: The best thing to do is use @BobHanlon 's answer where *Mathematica* has the built-in Frechet distribution.  And it would seem you should report this as a bug to Wolfram, Inc.

Comment: I know but i'm writing custom distribution and I'm fearing it will be wrong also

Comment: Being skeptical of software is a good thing.  Had you plotted the resulting cdf with some values of $\alpha$ and $\lambda$, you would have seen that cdf being negative.  Always verify things.

Comment: well, i will do thanks JimB